# Admob ads stop appearing inside the app for no reason

Tags: flutter, admob, ads

The ads were appearing normally, but suddenly, without any update of the application, the ads stopped appearing, I did not receive an email or any alert within the AdMob website.

When I try to contact technical support I get this message and I can't (something went wrong)

Comment: Google are disabling apps from play store that run Mature ads

Comment: Maybe google block ads from your app it happens when ads hit multiple times on a same screen

Comment: I have the same issue here!

Comment: how much revenue do you have on admob?